# Как и стоит ли декомпозировать вспомогательные функции на раннем этапе?

Tags: javascript, архитектура

В процессе разработки столкнулись с разногласиями по выносу одинакового кода(иногда он ещё не дублируется) в отдельные файлы(файл). Приведу подходы на примере вспомогательных(хелперов) функций.

#### Подход №1

Создать директорию `helpers`, в ней создать `index.js` и в нём описывать все функции-хелперы. Привожу пример ниже.

Функция хелпер `typeIs`:

```js
/**
 * Some imports ... 
 */

/**
 * Returns data type
 *
 * @param {*} type
 * @return {string}
 */
const typeIs = () => {
  return {}.toString.call(type).replace('\]', '').split(' ')[1];
};


/**
 * Куча функций помощников 
 */

export {
  ...
  typeIs
  ...
}
```

#### Подход №2

Создать директорию `helpers`, в ней создать `index.js` и в нём ПОДКЛЮЧАТЬ или управлять ПОДКЛЮЧЕНИЕМ функций. Привожу пример ниже.

Функция хелпер `typeIs`(так же наименован файл):

```js
/**
 * typeIs
 * 
 * Returns data type
 *
 * @param {*} type
 * @return {string}
 */
export default type => {
  return {}.toString.call(type).replace('\]', '').split(' ')[1];
};
```

Файл `index.js`:

```js
import typeIs from './typeIs';

...

/**
 * too much imports 
 */

...

export {
  ...
  typeIs
  ...
}
```

Мной отстаивается подход №2 так как:

- разделяется сборка от реализации;
- код становится более читаемым и понятным;
- в случаем модуля, то видна архитектура;
- мне так удобней)

Как решаются подобные проблемы в ваших командах?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Если я правильно вас понял, то тут вопрос стоит. Разделить ли утилиты по отдельным файлам и импортировать их в index.js либо реализовать их в самом index.js?
Если так то ответ и да и нет.

1. Увеличение кода в одном файле, читабельность самого файла
2. Увеличение файлов опять трудность. (тысячи файлов переключение поиск ....)

Я предпочитаю начинать с одного файла и выносить (рефакторить) только по надобности. Делать сразу не вижу надобности для одной или 2 маленьких функций. Мнение остальных может не совпадать, в холивар не звать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Вы за 3 вариант - я его не стал описывать.

Comment: В программировании всего не учтешь лишь можно следовать практикам. Вы создаете, а не копируете. Как делают все - стараются не мешать стили.

Answer (score 2):

Заведите директорию `utils`, а для каждой отдельной фунции-хелпера свой файл.

Функции экспортируете.

Далее через [именованный импорт](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import) добавляете их в нужные Вам файлы:

```
// внешней файл

export const helperFunction = () => {
    console.log("test")
}

// файл, где требуется данный хелпер

import { helperFunction } from "./utils/helperFunction"
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я так и делаю(но разношу ещё и по логике), но вопрос в том, как поступать на ранних этапах и как у вас в проекте поступают.

Comment: Красивее `index.js`, тогда можно не писать название функции после `utils`